# Angular material mat-grid-list vs grid

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, grid

What are the benefits of:

1. Angular material's `mat-grid-list`(https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview)

in comparison with:

2. `grid`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)?

`Grid` is supported by all modern browsers, even IE 10-11 supports with some tweaks. `mat-grid-list` may have a bit more support. Is that the only reason to use `mat-grid-list`? 
I don't see any reason for `mat-grid-list` if I don't need old browser support.

Comment: I feel like this question _could_ be boiled down to a more general/essential question of "why use a CSS framework instead of writing your own CSS"...

Comment: @AlexanderNied, Usually css framework solves some tasks, that not so easy to solve just by css. But in this case mat-grid-list doesn't solve anything additional. It is like to have framework, that provides div but names it <customDiv> with the same behavior.

Comment: That's fair. I must admit I'm not familiar with Angular Material.  At a glance, my _hunch_ would be that it keeps it in the material library for a uniform code landscape if you're already using angular material.  Also, perhaps more importantly, it provides a means of layout for people who may know the library/framework but may not be super familiar or comfortable with CSS.  Just speculating, though

Comment: Wondering this as well... Seems pointless.